# how to fix `visualization.ComboChart` when using string,timeofday,number together on google chart?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to create a ComboChart including three columns types string, timeofday, number but I Facing an error "All series on a given axis must be of the same data type" even the column types is there, how to fix that ?

please check the link: https://jsfiddle.net/minamagdy666/2jfn1uec/3/

```
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
   data.addColumn('string', 'Time of Day');
  data.addColumn('timeofday', 'Time of Day');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Emails Received');

  data.addRows([
    ['eee',[8, 30, 45], 5],
    ['eee',[9, 0, 0], 10],
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Total Emails Received Throughout the Day',
    height: 450,
    series: {0:{type: 'line'}}
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, need to define the `seriesType` for the chart.

`'line'`, `'area'`, `'bars'`, `'candlesticks'`, or `'steppedArea'`

```
seriesType: 'bars'
```

next, if each series is not the same type,
(in this case one is number, the other timeofday)
then each series must be on its own y-axis...

```
1: {targetAxisIndex: 1}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Time of Day');
  data.addColumn('timeofday', 'Time of Day');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Emails Received');
  data.addRows([
    ['eee',[8, 30, 45], 5],
    ['eee',[9, 0, 0], 10],
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Total Emails Received Throughout the Day',
    height: 450,
    seriesType: 'bars',
    series: {
      0:{
        type: 'line'
      },
      1: {
        targetAxisIndex: 1
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```